# Where could a call to an removed property be cached for WebAPI app?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I have a .NET Web API app that has started failing. The error is that it cannot find the setter of a method: `set_QueueLocation` on a specific class. That was a property on that class, but was removed. This code lives in a NuGet package that I have control over. I searched both solutions (the Web API one and the library with the class used to have `QueueLocation` property) and *QueueLocation* does not occur in either of them.

As I mentioned, the library is a NuGet package and when updating, I didn't update the assembly version (just the NuGet version). I'm thinking that when deploying, it looked at the version and then didn't update it. But I can't find out where that might be cached.

I tried :

- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\VWDWebCache`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

I'm on VS 2015, Windows 10 pro. Were would this assembly be cached? Or what else might be causing this issue?

### Update

This issue is occurring when I run it in debug mode directly from within VS.

Comment: You really should update the assembly version when you publish a nuget package.   Best suggestion is to test the website is running locally and if it is I would republish the whole website

Comment: I figured out that I should update the version, did that and re-ran it, but still calling old property. I'm running in debug mode directly in VS. The question is how to clean up my previous mess so it works again. Hence wondering where to clean it up.

Comment: delete all the dlls where site is published and push the new ones.  Maybe there is an old dll in the folder which is causing the issue

Comment: The situation I'm trying to fix is **not** a published site. It is the site VS setups up automatically when you hit F5 in VS to debug. Where are those files?

Comment: are you running in iis express or iis?

Comment: IIS, but again, the problem was occurring when I ran from within VS...no idea what it is using...

Comment: delete the .vs in the solution folder and try again

Comment: In the applicationhost.config file, it shows what folder it is using! Thanks!